# On Call HangUp, Media Recorder does not stop and save the recorded call

Tags: android, audio-recording, android-mediarecorder, phone-call

I'm New to Android Programming. I am trying to build a Call Recorder. I am able to detect Incoming calls and start the Media Recorder successfully and record voice. But on Call Disconnect, the Stop() method does not trigger. it stops when i close the app. Everything is working except the stop(). when i close the app the recordings are also saved.
How do i Stop() the recording after the call is disconnected?

```
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.media.MediaRecorder;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.telephony.TelephonyManager;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Calendar;

public class nCallReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {





MediaRecorder callrecorder = new MediaRecorder();

        if (intent.getStringExtra(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE).equals(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_RINGING)) {
            String incomingNumber = intent.getStringExtra(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_INCOMING_NUMBER);
            Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
            int tm = c.get(Calendar.DATE);
            int tx = c.get(Calendar.SECOND);
            String timex = tm+"-"+tx;


            callrecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
            callrecorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.MPEG_4);
            callrecorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_NB);

            callrecorder.setOutputFile(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/" + incomingNumber +"-"+ timex+"-"+tx+".mp4");
            try {
                callrecorder.prepare();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            callrecorder.start();

            if (intent.getStringExtra(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE).equals(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_IDLE)
                    || intent.getStringExtra(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE).equals(
                    TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_OFFHOOK)) {

                callrecorder.stop();
                callrecorder.release();
            }


        }
    }
}
```

**

## EDIT 2

**
How Do i Stop() the media Recorder?
I tried instantiating the

> MediaRecorder r;

Globally but,

> r.stop()

Does not work, because r is not instantiated.

If it is possible to save the state of this MediaRecorder Instance, and use it with the stop method later on, How do i do it?

```
public class nCallRecorder extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        if (intent.getStringExtra(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE).equals(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_RINGING)) {
            //start recording
            String CallNo = intent.getStringExtra(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_INCOMING_NUMBER);
            MediaRecorder r = new MediaRecorder();
            r.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
            r.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.MPEG_4);
            r.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_NB);
            r.setOutputFile(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath()+"/"+CallNo+".mp4");
            try { r.prepare(); } catch(IOException e) { e.printStackTrace(); }
            r.start();

        } else if (intent.getStringExtra(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE).equals(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_IDLE)) {
            //stop recording
            Toast.makeText(context,"Call Ends",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Just declaring a `MediaRecorder` isn't sufficient. You still have to assign it a `MediaRecorder` instance somewhere (i.e. `r = new MediaRecorder();`). You could do that when you start recording, right before `r.setAudioSource`.

Answer (score 0):

The check for whether the state has changed to `IDLE` appears to be inside the `if intent.getStringExtra(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE).equals(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_RINGING)) {`. You probably want something like this instead:

```
if (intent.getStringExtra(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE).equals(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_RINGING)) {
    // start recording
} else if (intent.getStringExtra(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE).equals(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_IDLE) {
    // stop recording
}
```

---

Also, you're creating a new `MediaRecorder` instance every time your `BroadcastReceiver` is invoked. You should only create a `MediaRecorder` instance when you start recording, and save that instance so that you can stop it later on.

---

Another minor thing is that you have `intent.getStringExtra(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE).equals(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_OFFHOOK)` in your condition for whether the recording should be stopped. "Off-hook" doesn't mean that you've hung up; it means that *"at least one call exists that is dialing, active, or on hold"*.

Comment: How do i save the MediaRecorder instance? and also, how do i reuse the saved state?